# declaring a fuction() in the <script> tag necessary?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I have started learning web development languages to make a website. have studied html and css. Now learning java script from w3schools website. While learning about function I got stuck in one tricky code.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>A local variable can only be accessed from within the function where it was declared.</p>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    myFunction();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    "I can display " + typeof carName;

    function myFunction() {
    var carName = "Volvo";
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

So my question is, why myFunction(); was declared in the script tag?
I was learning some function block earlier, but never encounter with such code EG:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>This example calls a function which performs a calculation, and returns the result:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function myFunction(a, b) {
    return a * b;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(4, 3);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

in these code the function name is not declared in the script tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **call** a function, **you have to declare** it first.
So, in your example the declaration of the function is this:

```
function myFunction(a, b) {
return a * b;
}
```

And this is the call:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(4, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you refer to the line

```
myFunction();
```

when you talk about declaring a function. But this is not a declaration but a *call* to the function. The example is about the declaration of variable `carName`.

Answer (score 0):

`myFunction()` isn't the declaration. `function myFunction()...` is the declaration. `myFunction()` *calls* the function.

In the first example the function is called without passing in any parameters. All the function does is declare the variable `carName` and assign it the 'Volvo' value.

In the second example the function is being called with 2 parameters `myFunction(4, 3)`. The function returns the product of those two numbers.

It is assigned as the inner HTML of the element with the id "demo":

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(4, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function here actually and not declaring. it will be called when the page loads.

without that line, the codes inside the myFunction() will not execute

Answer (score 0):

your code is wrong change the code to this and it will run correctly.

```
<script>
   function myFunction() {
    var carName = "Volvo";
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    "I can display " +  carName;
    }
     myFunction();

 </script>
```

Now about myFunction().You created a function called myFunction.

To create a function, type the function keyword followed by a name for the function, followed by an opening, then a closing, parentheses, followed by an opening curly bracket “{“ and ending with a closing curly bracket “}”.
You can give it any name in your case you named it myFunction();.e.g

```
function myFunction(){
code to be executed ..
}
```

The function keyword is required. It lets the browser know that you are creating a function.
The name of the function:

```
Must start with a letter or an underscore
Can contain letters, digits, and underscores in any combination
Cannot contain space
Cannot contain special characters
```

now about myFunction(); at the end of your code. it is called function calling. Using a function is referred to as calling the function. when you call a function it gets executed.